# VMware ballooning state from inside guest

Tags: linux, centos, esxi

There's tools (e.g. [extop](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1008205)) to check VMware ballooning state from VMware host.

I'm using VMware to run CentOS 6.3 and when ballooning stars consume memory to reclaim it back to ESX host, my system behaves not nicely under the stress.

Is there way to see the ballooning state from inside guest system?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Install the VMware tools and use

```
vmware-toolbox-cmd stat balloon
```

or

```
cat /proc/vmmemctl
```

to check.

Comment: Wow, thanks. I was looking for it for a long time :)

Answer (score 6):

With recent Linux kernel module `vmw_balloon`, `vmmemctl` has moved to `debugfs`. You have to mount it (if not already done, like on Ubuntu) to check memory target and current values in pages:

```
lsmod | grep balloon
vmw_balloon            12542  0
mount -t debugfs none /sys/kernel/debug
cat /sys/kernel/debug/vmmemctl
```